# Glympse API append_data error

Tags: glympse

I am trying to append_data to a Glympse ticket and I am getting a serialization error. I have tried many variation on the following request body and can not seem to make a successful call:

{
    [
        "n" : "destination",
        "v" : {
            "lat" : 43345678,
            "lng" : -121456789
        }
    ]
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The timestamp field is required https://developer.glympse.com/docs/core/api/reference/tickets/id/append_data/post

[{"v":{"lng":-121456789,"lat":43345678},"t":1513869134948,"n":"destination"}]

Comment: Thanks Nick, I had actually tried it with the timestamp. I think what I actually didn't have figured out was the layering of the array and the objects. It is shown differently between the "body" and the example in the documentation (array inside of object vs. object inside of array).

Comment: You're right, it is wrong in the document there. I'll submit a fix :)